# Header for checkbox

Tags: usability, gui-design, checkboxes

What is the better choice for designing the header for a column of checkboxes? Referring to the mockup, on the left is a label and a checkbox while on the left is only the checkbox. The checkbox is there in the header because to act as a "select all" feature.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRUGV4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: This question is unclear. Can you add some detail about the use-case you are trying to design for to help us understand what you're asking? Maybe you could add some contextual detail to your wirefame too?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need, in this table, the heading, with the title "Options / Select" and "Select all" in the footer. This is clearer.

You have two options for "Select all":

- It is a button. In this case, you can keep it simple or you can design it like a button.
- If you want to use a checkbox, in this case, it is important to differentiate it from the other checkboxes (a smaller margin in left, or bigger).

Answer (score 1):

I assume all checkboxes will have labels.
It would be better to leave the header to be just header and add an extra checkbox labeled 'All' or 'Select all'.
Below is an example of filter dialog in a spreadsheet, with a separate checkbox for 'All'

[image: filter dialog with checkboxes from LibreOffice Calc]